# Data binding in D3 fails when using "cloned" data

Tags: d3.js

D3 data binding seem to be behave differently when using the original data object, vs. using a cloned version of the data object. I have a function **updateTable** which updates an array of tables based on the passed array of arrays. If an array (representing one new table row) is added to the array of arrays, and passed to the **updateFunction**, all works as expected (the row is added to the table). If however, we make a shallow copy (clone) of this data structure and pass it to the **updateFunction**, the data binding fails and no table row is added. Please note that the original data structure and clone are two different objects, however with **identical values**.

Please see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bsnkteju/1/) JSFiddle example. Two tables are generated, one fed the original data, the other the cloned data. The two tables are clearly different, as the second table (built using cloned data) does **NOT** contain the third row.

```
'use strict';
d3.select("body").append("h3").text("D3 Data Binding Issue");

// create two divs to hold one table each
var tableDiv1 = d3.select("body").append("div");
d3.select("body").append("hr");
var tableDiv2 = d3.select("body").append("div");

// define data
// here, an array of a single item (which represents a table), containing an array of arrays, 
// each destined for a table row
var data = [
  { table: "Table1", rows: [
      { table: "Table1", row: "Row1", data: "DataT1R1" },
      { table: "Table1", row: "Row2", data: "DataT1R2" }
    ]
  }
];

// run update on the initial data
update(data);

// add 3rd array to the data structure (which should add a third row in each table)
data[0].rows.push({ table: "Table1", row: "Row3", data: "DataT1R3" });

// run update again
// observe that the Lower table (which is using cloned data) does NOT update
update(data);

/*
// remove first array of the data structure
data[0].rows.shift();

// run update again
// observe that the Lower table (which again is using cloned data) does NOT update
update(data);
*/

// function to run the tableUpdate function targeting two different divs, one with the 
// original data, and the other with cloned data
function update(data) {
  // the contents of the two data structures are equal
  console.log("\nAre object values equal? ", JSON.stringify(data) == JSON.stringify(clone(data)));

  tableUpdate(data, tableDiv1, "Using Original Data"); // update first table
  tableUpdate(clone(data), tableDiv2, "Using Cloned Data"); // update second table
}

// generic function to manage array of tables (in this simple example only one table is managed)
function tableUpdate(data, tableDiv, title) {
  console.log("data", JSON.stringify(data));

  // get all divs in this table div 
  var divs = tableDiv.selectAll("div")
      .data(data, function(d) { return d.table }); // disable default by-index eval

  // remove div(s)
  divs.exit().remove();

  // add new div(s)
  var divsEnter = divs.enter().append("div");

  // append header(s) in new div(s)
  divsEnter.append("h4").text(title);

  // append table(s) in new div(s)
  var tableEnter = divsEnter.append("table")
      .attr("id", function(d) { return d.table });

  // append table body in new table(s)
  tableEnter.append("tbody");

  // select all tr elements in the divs update selection
  var tr = divs.selectAll("table").selectAll("tbody").selectAll("tr")
      .data(function(d, i, a) { return d.rows; }, function(d, i, a) { return d.row; }); // disable by-index eval

  // remove any row(s) with missing data array(s)
  tr.exit().remove();

  // add row(s) for new data array(s)
  tr.enter().append("tr");

  // bind data to table cells
  var td = tr.selectAll("td")
      .data(function(d, i) { return d3.values(d); });

  // add new cells
  td.enter().append("td");

  // update contents of table cells
  td.text(function(d) { return d; });
}

// source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm
function clone(objectToBeCloned) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectToBeCloned));

}
```

Can anybody shed some light on this behavior? I believe I'm using the key functions properly, but could be wrong. In my application I need to re-generate the data structure before each table update, and I don't have option of reusing the original object.

Comment: Well the root of the problem is that you have a nested structure and `.selectAll()` doesn't update the data bound to the elements (but `.append()` automatically "inherits" the data). So the data that you use to render the table is simply not updated -- you can fix this by using `.select()` instead of `.selectAll()` (https://jsfiddle.net/bsnkteju/2/). No idea why it works for the original data though.

Comment: Thanks! The script now works as intended with changing `selectAll()` to `select()`. Personally, I don't understand why this change was needed, as I thought `selectAll()` is a superset of `select()` and both would behave the same way if there is only one element (which there is in this case). Then there still is the open issue of the behavior difference when using original vs. "cloned" data

Comment: The subtle difference between `.select()` and `.selectAll()` is that the former (similar to `.append()`) "inherits" the data bound to the elements in the current selection to the newly selected elements, while `.selectAll()` does not.

Comment: Very interesting question!

Answer (score 2):

The root of the problem is that you have a nested structure and `.selectAll()` doesn't update the data bound to the elements (but `.append()` automatically "inherits" the data). So the data that you use to render the table is simply not updated -- you can fix this by using `.select()` instead of `.selectAll()` (see the [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/bsnkteju/2)).

The subtle difference between `.select()` and `.selectAll()` is that the former (similar to `.append()`) "inherits" the data bound to the elements in the current selection to the newly selected elements, while `.selectAll()` does not.

So why does it work for the original data? Well, D3 doesn't copy the data when it binds it to an element, but references it. By modifying the original data, you're also modifying what's bound to the elements. Hence simply running the code without rebinding any data works. The cloned data isn't updated as you're not modifying it directly.

Comment: I think `selectAll` _does_ inherit @Lars.  There will be one node created for each element in the array bound to the parent (if the data bound is not an array then no child nodes will be selected or created), so, the child nodes inherit the _elements of_ the parent data when using `selectAll`.  The difference is that the whole array is bound to the (first qualifying) child element when using `select` and the parent of that selected node is set to the `html` element.

Comment: @CoolBlue Nope, see the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#selectAll): "The subselection does not inherit data from the current selection".

Comment: Ah, Ok. It's the `data` method that's actually doing the deed. Got it... I have to admit that this part of d3 (and I'm talking about `select` vs `selectAll`, binding and key functions) is the most confusing for me, that's why I took the time to analyse it a bit. Slowly I'm getting there.

Comment: Yes, I can see why `.select()` and `.selectAll()` were implemented how they are, but this is certainly one of the most confusing parts of D3 that's bound to introduce subtle and hard to detect bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the problem is due to an anti-pattern that you are using to "muscle" the `tr` structure.

### The problem

During the second pass through tableUpdate, the key function finds a match on d.table for both the original and the un-cloned data.  This is because the key is converted to a string during the binding process so even though

```
d.table === data.table;    // false
```

it's still a match because

```
d.table == data.table;    // true
```

Therefore the enter selection is empty in both cases and all of this code

```
  var divsEnter = divs.enter().append("div");

  // append header(s) in new div(s)
  divsEnter.append("h4").text(title);

  // append table(s) in new div(s)
  var tableEnter = divsEnter.append("table")
      .attr("id", function(d) { return d.table });

  // append table body in new table(s)
  tableEnter.append("tbody");
```

does nothing.
***So the original data is not re-bound and the new, cloned data is not bound.  But...***
the data bound to the first table now has three rows because, as Lars pointed out, it is bound by reference.  so, for the first table,

```
divs.datum() === data;     // true
```

and it now has three rows.

In the case of the cloned data, the key function also returns true because you haven't changed it. Even though it has an extra row, data.key is still "Table1".  So you are telling the key function that it's the same table. Consequently, the enter selection is also empty so, the new, cloned data is also not bound so, for the second table,

```
divs.datum() === data;     // false
d.table == data.table == "Table1"  // um, true true
```

and it still has two rows.

The problem is you use an an anti-pattern to bind the data and build the `tr` elements.

Instead of selecting and binding the data following the hierarchy of it's structure, you go *off piste* and go back to the `div` and just ram it down to the `tr` element to build the structure.  This is dangerous because the returned `tr` elements are *unqualified*, none of the important context that you gained from carefully selecting/creating the correct `tbody` element is used to ensure that these are the  correct `tr` elements, they are in fact, whatever `tr` elements that happen to be laying around - regardless of which `table` they belong to - inside the `div`.

In both cases you simply rebuild the tr elements using the original arrays that are still attached, which is fine for the first table but for the second one... not so much.

> My "current theory" of best practice is to build your data structure to model the intended structure of your visualisation first and then construct the DOM elements by walking that data structure, binding at each level and kicking the remaining data ahead of you as you go, until finally, it's all bound.

### The solution

You need to be truly "data driven" and strictly follow the data structure when building and binding your elements.  I re-built your updateTable function below...

```js
'use strict';

d3.select("body").append("h3").text("D3 Data Binding Issue").style({margin:0});

// create two divs to hold one table each
var tableDiv1 = d3.select("body").append("div");
var tableDiv2 = d3.select("body").append("div");

// define data
// here, an array of a single item (which represents a table), containing an array of arrays, 
// each destined for a table row
var data = [{
    table: "Table1",
    rows: [{
        table: "Table1",
        row: "Row1",
        data: "DataT1R1"
    }, {
        table: "Table1",
        row: "Row2",
        data: "DataT1R2"
    }]
}];

// run update on the initial data
update(data);
update(data);

// add 3rd array to the data structure (which should add a third row in each table)
data[0].rows.push({
    table: "Table1",
    row: "Row3",
    data: "DataT1R3"
});

// run update again
// observe that the Lower table (which is using cloned data) does NOT update
update(data);

/*
// remove first array of the data structure
data[0].rows.shift();

// run update again
// observe that the Lower table (which again is using cloned data) does NOT update
update(data);
*/

// function to run the tableUpdate function targeting two different divs, one with the 
// original data, and the other with cloned data
function update(data) {
    // the contents of the two data structures are equal
    console.log("\nAre object values equal? ", JSON.stringify(data) == JSON.stringify(clone(data)));

    tableUpdate(data, tableDiv1, "Using Original Data"); // update first table
    tableUpdate(clone(data), tableDiv2, "Using Cloned Data"); // update second table
}

// generic function to manage array of tables (in this simple example only one table is managed)
function tableUpdate(data, tableDiv, title) {
    console.log("data", JSON.stringify(data));

    // get all divs in this table div 
    var divs = tableDiv.selectAll("div")
        .data(data, function (d) {
        return d.table
    }); // disable default by-index eval

    // remove div(s)
    divs.exit().remove();

    // add new div(s)
    var divsEnter = divs.enter().append("div");

    // append header(s) in new div(s)
    divsEnter.append("h4").text(title);

    // append or replace table(s) in new div(s)
    var table = divs.selectAll("table")
        .data(function (d) {
        // the 1st dimension determines the number of elements
        // this needs to be 1 (one table)
        return [d.rows];
    }, function (d) {
        // need a unique key to diferenciate table generations
   var sha256 = new jsSHA("SHA-256", "TEXT");
            return (sha256.update(JSON.stringify(d)), 
                console.log([this.length ? "data" : "node", sha256.getHash('HEX')].join("\t")), 
                sha256.getHash('HEX'));
    });
    table.exit().remove();
    // the table body will have the same data pushed down from the table
    // it will also be the array of array of rows
    table.enter().append("table").append("tbody");
    console.log(table.enter().size() ? "new table" : "same table")
    var tBody = table.selectAll("tbody");

    // select all tr elements in the divs update selection
    var tr = tBody.selectAll("tr")
        .data(function (d, i, a) {
        // return one element of the rows array
        return d;
    }, function (d, i, a) {
        return d.row;
    }); // disable by-index eval

    // remove any row(s) with missing data array(s)
    tr.exit().remove();

    // add row(s) for new data array(s)
    tr.enter().append("tr");

    // bind data to table cells
    var td = tr.selectAll("td")
        .data(function (d, i) {
        return d3.values(d);
    });

    // add new cells
    td.enter().append("td");

    // update contents of table cells
    td.text(function (d) {
        return d;
    });
}

// source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm
function clone(objectToBeCloned) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectToBeCloned));

}
```

```css
table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
body>div { display: inline-block; margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsSHA/2.0.1/sha.js"></script>
```

### The interesting thing(s)

The interesting thing is, that the table bound to the original data never gets replaced.  The reason being that, again, as mentioned by @Lars, the data is bound by reference.
As an experiment (and inspired by my love-hate relationship with git) I used a 256 bit sha as a key, feeding the stringified data to it.  If you're managing a bunch of tables in the same space then maybe this is the way to go.  If you always clone the data and calculate a sha then that feels like a very secure approach.

By way of illustration, here is a redacted log (I added a second update with the same data at the start...)

This is the first pass where there are no nodes yet.  The key function is only invoked once on each data element because the update selection is empty.

```
Are object values equal?  true
data [{"table":"Table1","rows":[{"tab...,"data":"DataT1R2"}]}]
 data   a09a5ef8f6b81669eed13c93f609884...
 new table                           ...
data [{"table":"Table1","rows":[{"tab...,"data":"DataT1R2"}]}]
 data   a09a5ef8f6b81669eed13c93f609884...
 new table                           ...
                                     ...
```

This is the second call with the same data.  You can see that the key function is called twice for each table and that the sha is the same for both, hence the "same table" anotation.

```
Are object values equal?  true             ...
data [{"table":"Table1","rows":[{"tab...,"data":"DataT1R2"}]}]
 node   a09a5ef8f6b81669eed13c93f609884...
 data   a09a5ef8f6b81669eed13c93f609884...
 same table                          ...
data [{"table":"Table1","rows":[{"tab...,"data":"DataT1R2"}]}]
 node   a09a5ef8f6b81669eed13c93f60...
 data   a09a5ef8f6b81669eed13c93f60...
 same table
```

Here is the interesting case where, even though the data has changed, the key function returns the same sha for node and data for the first table.  The second table is as expected, with different sha for node and data and a new table generated.

```
Are object values equal?  true
data [{"table":"Table1","rows":[{...,"data":"DataT1R3"}]}]
 node   7954982db25aee37483face1602...
 data   7954982db25aee37483face1602...
 same table                      ...
data [{"table":"Table1","rows":[{...,"data":"DataT1R3"}]}]
 node   a09a5ef8f6b81669eed13c93f60...
 data   7954982db25aee37483face1602...
 new table
```

Comment: Interesting analysis, but I don't think that the issue is really caused by the key function here (although you're of course right that this is something that should be fixed as well).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I'm not actually saying that the problem is the key function, although using the key function increases the number of failure modes if you deviate from the canonical, I'm saying that this code is the problem: `var tr = divs.selectAll("table").selectAll("tbody").selectAll("tr")
          .data(function(d, i, a) { return d.rows; }, function(d, i, a) { return d.row; });` Although you have to admit also, that using a key that does not establish the uniqueness of the data is a big part of the problem. At the very least, it's a waste of time, no?

Comment: Yep, and one solution to fix it is yours (restructuring), but it also works with just the `.select()` instead of the `.selectAll()`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, in this instance yes but it's not scalable. (For my own benefit as much as anything else) I wanted to register a general pattern that will also work for multiple tables.

Comment: Thanks very much LarsKotthoff and CoolBlue for explanations and code samples! Much appreciated responses (to my very first question on SO, btw).

Comment: @CoolBlue Depends what you mean by "scalable". It will work with this general structure where a top level element contains a series of single children. There can be an arbitrary number of top level elements, it will only break if there's more than one child (which in this case it seems there won't be).

Comment: Your welcome @BoEricsson and welcome to Stack Overflow! It's a very nice question because it examines one of the trickiest (and one of the most powerful) parts of d3. I suggest you accept Lars' answer as the best way of thanking him :)

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, exactly, it only works for a single element and it's not data driven to do it like that: having selected your way down to the `tbody` element and potentially holding a nicely wrapped reference to that, you throw it away and go back and select your way down from the `div`. That feels unnecessarily imperative and it is the reason it broke, because it short circuited to the existing `tr` elements. But anyway, it's all good fun :)